# Sync google+ Albums with Nexus 5

Tags: sync, nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop, photos

Is there a possibility to sync my google+ photo albums to my Nexus 5?

My Galaxy Nexus, with the old gallery app, had the feature to "pin" albums locally to the device. My new Nexus 5, with the new photos app, dosn't seem to have this feature.

The photos app shows all my g+ albums, but always needs to load them from the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.gplusexpertise.com/2014/11/photos-update-in-android-50-lollipop.html), it is (currently) not possible:

> You can view and manage your albums when logged in to the Google+ Photo app. We do not offer the ability to view albums offline at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it does not work for albums (at least with the Google photos app version 4.8.0.81189390).

I'm using this app as a workaround, because it allows to sync the albums for offline access.

Tool for Picasa, Google+ Photo
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=larry.zou.colorfullife